# how to install kubeflow on existing on prem kubernetes cluster

Tags: jupyter-notebook, istio, kubernetes-pod, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am installing kubeflow on kubernetes cluster via "Kubeflow Deployment with kfctl_k8s_istio"
and it is giving below error.

```
WARN[0303] Encountered error applying application kubeflow-apps:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run : error when creating "/tmp/kout497340857": CustomResourceDefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "seldondeployments.machinelearning.seldon.io" is invalid: [spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[predictors].items.properties[componentSpecs].items.properties[spec].properties[containers].items.properties[ports].items.properties[protocol].default: Required value: this property is in x-kubernetes-list-map-keys, so it must have a default or be a required property, spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[predictors].items.properties[componentSpecs].items.properties[spec].properties[initContainers].items.properties[ports].items.properties[protocol].default: Required value: this property is in x-kubernetes-list-map-keys, so it must have a default or be a required property, spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[predictors].items.properties[explainer].properties[containerSpec].properties[ports].items.properties[protocol].default: Required value: this property is in x-kubernetes-list-map-keys, so it must have a default or be a required property]  filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:266"
```

Some Istio PODs are not starting and giving below error on kubernetes dashboard.

```
"MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istio-token" : failed to fetch token: the API server does not have TokenRequest endpoints enabled"
```

Please support.

Comment: What is your infrastructure? What is your k8s version? Did you see that [github issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959)?

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

Why do we see this error?

```
"MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istio-token" : failed to fetch token: the API server does not have TokenRequest endpoints enabled"
```

As mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens)

> To authenticate with the Istio control plane, the Istio proxy will use a Service Account token. Kubernetes supports two forms of these tokens:
>
> - Third party tokens, which have a scoped audience and expiration.
> - First party tokens, which have no expiration and are mounted into all pods.
>
> Because the properties of the first party token are less secure, Istio will default to using third party tokens. However, this feature is not enabled on all Kubernetes platforms.
>
> While most cloud providers support this feature now, many local development tools and custom installations may not.

---

### Solution

**If you use minikube**

You can specify that with `values.global.jwtPolicy`

```
istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo --set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt
```

There is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24746) about that.

---

**If you use microk8s**

You can try to change these 2 lines to /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-apiserver as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959#issuecomment-593489258) by @tomalbrecht.

```
--service-account-signing-key-file=${SNAP_DATA}/certs/serviceaccount.key
--service-account-issuer=kubernetes.default.svc
```

There is related [github issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959) about that.

---

**If you use kubeadm**

You can try with [this](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959#issuecomment-593289634).